# How to create google play app with my website?

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview, apk, google-play-developer-api

I want my website should act as Google play store app.

For example, go to-> [hytoz](http://www.hytoz.com/)
and [hytoz app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wHytoz&hl=en)

Both source are same. But when I open this app, website will shown as app and after click back or close, it's asking confirm like application.

How I can make this? I'm not android person. I'm in PHP.

Comment: any one can put -1. but tell me WHY...

Answer (score 1):

First of all, making Android app isn't a one click process. To make a simple Android app, you can make use of Android [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Since you're new to Android, I'd suggest you to take courses on [basics of Android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html).

You've mentioned you're familiar with PHP. You can better try **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)**, with basics of HTML5, CSS3 and JS, you can build an app. Also, your needs like back, close can also be done with it, and moreover, it's cross platform, you can ship to other operating systems too.

Good Luck.